# Transform Storm Liouville eq. into integral equation

Tags: integration

[image]

I rewrote the left side as a derivative of product,  i have to find fundamental system and write Green function? can someone help me in solving? thank you

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Write your questions clearly and more specifically.

Comment: hm i need to transforme this equation into integral equation...